# TinyCore Linux & RVM

Tags: bash, ruby

I'm running TinyCore Linux and when I tried to install RVM (needed a portable linux distro for QA Automation) I keep getting an error `sh: syntax error:unexpected redirection`.

I am unsure why I am getting this error since the `echo $SHELL` command returns BASH.

Any ideas on how I could get this working or get more details on the issue?

Comment: Some more detail on what commands you ran, how far they got, etc. might be useful.

Comment: @karpie Unfortunately, that is as far as it got once I typed in the command: bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)

Answer (score 4):

Your Tiny Core Linux install probably has a bare-minimum shell installed.  This is probably [busybox](http://www.busybox.net/about.html).  You can verify this by checking if `/bin/sh` is symlinked to something else:

```
ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Dec 15 20:52 /bin/sh -> busybox
```

Since Tiny Core Linux loads the bare-minimum OS into RAM, this is desirable.  However, if you need a more fully-featured shell you may install it via the [Application Browser](http://wiki.tinycorelinux.net/wiki:getting_started#getting_applications) (See the [List of available applications here](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/tcz_2x.html), the command-line version of the application browser is `tce-ab`).  Tiny Core Linux currently has: `bash` and `tcsh`.

To install bash:

```
tce-load -wi bash.tcz
```

The default shell is still `/bin/sh`, however you can spawn a bash shell by running `bash` from within it.

To set the `tcuser`'s default shell:

```
which bash | sudo tee -a /etc/shells > /dev/null
sudo sed -i "/$(cat /etc/sysconfig/tcuser)/ s#:[^:]\+\$#:$(which bash)#" /etc/passwd
```

You might want to also install the GNU `coreutils` if you're looking for more GNU standard utilities for use in bash scripts also:

```
tce-load -wi coreutils.tcz
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one of the scripts is running under `/bin/sh` but uses extended features of bash, possibly `<<<` or `<(`. You presumably have ash as `/bin/sh`; that's legitimate (and ash is measurably faster and uses less memory than bash, which is why many distributions don't put bash as `/bin/sh`), but occasionally you run into scripts that rely on bash yet start with `#!/bin/sh`.

That you have `$SHELL` set to bash is irrelevant, each script is executed by the shell indicated on the first line (the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), here `#!/bin/sh`). I've had a quick look at the RVM scripts, and it looks like all the ones that rely on bash extensions correctly start with `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. Do you have a prior existing `~/.rvm`? If so, try moving it out of the way.

You can get an execution trace for a shell script by running the shell with the `-x` option. So run `bash -x ./rvm` and see where the error occurs. If the error occurs in a script called indirectly from the main `rvm` script, try adding `set -x` in the other scripts as well (immediately below the `#!` line), to see an execution trace for them. This should help locate the offending script.